# List users by average points on Hacker News?

Tags: hacker-news

I know that one can list users by most karma but this is not very useful to show those with great commentary. For example, [Joel Spolsky](http://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=spolsky) has an average of 27.27 yet is not on the leader board because his karma is not high enough. As a matter of fact not even [Paul Graham](http://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=pg) is on the list.

I am assuming that based on incremental privileges one gets with karma (for example the ability to downvote) one will reach a stage where this feature (list of users sorted by average) will be available.

Comment: HN's "average" points are weird because they're calculated on a random, sporadic basis http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2632222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They stopped showing average karma because it was gamed by some users.

I reached out to Daniel from Hacker News, for comment;

> We used to display average karma but some users were gaming this by
>   deleting all their comments that didn't get upvoted. I'm not sure the
>   number is that meaningful.
>
> PG never was on the leader board because he specifically exempted
>   himself from it.
>
> I agree with you that the list of leaders by most karma is pretty
>   useless and the only reason we haven't change it is that I'm not sure
>   what to replace it with.
>
> Daniel (dang)